# Change text on accordion header when clicked or opened with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a collapsible footer and I want the text to change from "open" to "close" when clicked.  I have this part figured out.  The problem I'm having is I also want the footer to expand and the text to change in the same way when a button/link is clicked.  Any help would be appreciated!

```js
//collapse footer
$("#collapseOne").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 999999 }, "slow");
});

//switch between open and close when footer is clicked

 $('.switchCopy').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('switchCopy');
    if($this.hasClass('switchCopy')){
      $this.text('open');     
    } else {
      $this.text('close');
    }
  });
```

```css
section {
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.red {
  background: #f98383;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ecec87;
}

.green {
  background: #c1ffc1;
}


/*footer accordion */

#accordion {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background: #FF4040;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #FF4040;
}

.panel-title a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: none;
}

.panel-title a:hover,
.panel-title a:focus,
.panel-title a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="green">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <p class="lead">Suspendisse ac libero maximus, sollicitudin ligula a, tempus turpis. Duis cursus, felis nec molestie cursus, nibh quam laoreet elit, id fringilla velit leo nec neque. Aenean nibh neque, ultricies non tortor non, lacinia suscipit nulla. Quisque
          in ultrices ante. Ut dignissim, urna ut egestas ornare, nulla erat accumsan augue, at fermentum libero eros semper ligula. Phasellus efficitur eros ac leo posuere, ultrices venenatis risus rutrum. Nullam facilisis volutpat pellentesque.</p>
          <a href="#collapseOne"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Primary link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <p class="panel-title m-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="switchCopy">
                  open
                </a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 align-self-center">
                Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante, quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet.Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna
                maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante, quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet. Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante,
                quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</footer>
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was giving your button a new class primary-link and added two scrips which change the text of your link on click events, using the ternary operator which basically is the short version of if else-statement.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```js
//collapse footer
$("#collapseOne").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 999999 }, "slow");
});

//switch between open and close when footer is clicked

$('.primary-link').click(function(){
  $('.switchCopy').text($('.switchCopy').text() == 'close' ? 'open' : 'close');
});

$('.switchCopy').click(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'close' ? 'open' : 'close');
});
```

```css
section {
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.red {
  background: #f98383;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ecec87;
}

.green {
  background: #c1ffc1;
}


/*footer accordion */

#accordion {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background: #FF4040;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #FF4040;
}

.panel-title a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: none;
}

.panel-title a:hover,
.panel-title a:focus,
.panel-title a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="green">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <p class="lead">Suspendisse ac libero maximus, sollicitudin ligula a, tempus turpis. Duis cursus, felis nec molestie cursus, nibh quam laoreet elit, id fringilla velit leo nec neque. Aenean nibh neque, ultricies non tortor non, lacinia suscipit nulla. Quisque
          in ultrices ante. Ut dignissim, urna ut egestas ornare, nulla erat accumsan augue, at fermentum libero eros semper ligula. Phasellus efficitur eros ac leo posuere, ultrices venenatis risus rutrum. Nullam facilisis volutpat pellentesque.</p>
          <a href="#collapseOne"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active primary-link" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Primary link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <p class="panel-title m-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="switchCopy">
                  open
                </a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 align-self-center">
                Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante, quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet.Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna
                maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante, quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet. Cras id ex quis sapien condimentum aliquet a vitae turpis. In imperdiet magna maximus nunc ultricies maximus. Donec congue lobortis ante,
                quis convallis purus iaculis sit amet.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish this add your text toggle code within the "on show" accordion event handler, and also add an "on hide" accordion event handler with the same text toggle logic.  I'd put the text toggle logic in its own function.  For example:

```
var $switch = $('.switchCopy');
//changes footer text based on inclusion of switchCopy class
function toggleAccordionText() {
    $switch.toggleClass('switchCopy');
    if($switch.hasClass('switchCopy')){
      $switch.text('open');     
    } else {
      $switch.text('close');
    }
};

//show footer
$("#collapseOne").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 999999 }, "slow");
  toggleAccordionText();
//hide footer
}).on("hide.bs.collapse", toggleAccordionText);

//switch between open and close when footer is clicked
$switch.click(toggleAccordionText);
```